# How to solve (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind) Exception with out using @JsonIgnore

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have been getting this Exception when getting data if I don't use `@JsonIgnore` annotation on mapped method

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:678)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:112)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:672)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:678)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:672)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:678)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:112)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:672)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:678)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
```

please have a look at entity class

```
package com.rasvek.cg.entity;
// Generated May 14, 2018 11:39:07 PM by Hibernate Tools 5.1.7.Final

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

/**
 * MasterCampusClass generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "master_campus_class", catalog = "campus_guru_01")
public class MasterCampusClass implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer classId;
    private String className;
    private String classShortName;
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "class_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getClassId() {
        return this.classId;
    }

    public void setClassId(Integer classId) {
        this.classId = classId;
    }

    @Column(name = "class_name")
    public String getClassName() {
        return this.className;
    }

    public void setClassName(String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }

    @Column(name = "class_short_name")  
    public String getClassShortName() {
        return this.classShortName;
    }


//@JsonIgnore  
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "masterCampusClass")
    public Set<MasterCampusSection> getMasterCampusSections() {
        return this.masterCampusSections;
    }

    public void setMasterCampusSections(Set<MasterCampusSection> masterCampusSections) {
        this.masterCampusSections = masterCampusSections;
    }
}
```

If I use @JsonIgnore , when i am saving `MasterCampusSections`  is not accepting json , it's not receiving as json because of @jsonIgnore annotation

Can't we solve the above exception without using @JsonIgnore annotation?

If possible please let me know! Thank you.

Comment: We could the type of `Exception` thrown there. Your stack trace begins by `at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`, somewhere over those lines is the exception itself. It may help us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it seems you're trying to do is maintain a parent-child entity reference. Try using the `@JsonManagedReference` annotation in `MasterCampusClass` and `@JsonBackReference` on the matching field in `MasterCampusSection`.

If, however, you need an explicit value referencing the parent class inside the JSON (like an id), you have to use custom serializers at both ends. Both the `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonIgnore` annotations will make it ignore custom serializers.

Comment: thank you @coladict its working , thank you very much